# When the waitress at a diner calls her male customer a ''good girl'' after getting tipped, is it meant to be offensive?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, phrases, idioms, semantics

My friend got called that and since neither of us are American, it just sounded offensive to us.

Comment: I would need more context but as a native speaker of AmE, I cannot readily imagine when that would make sense in a non-offensive usage.

Comment: Probably due to the fact that American waiters and waitresses expect, and generally receive, far higher tips than we normally give in the UK. Ten percent of the bill, in my experience, is an absolute minimum, and twenty percent is not unusual in some places.

Comment: Offense has to be in the eye (ear) of the speaker or the person being spoken about. It is not really possible to guess from outside the immediate context.

Comment: Wouldn't the fact it's directed at a man be offensive in itself?

Comment: Either offensive, or a slip of the tongue, or you misunderstood what she said, or she really believed that your friend was a girl.

Comment: @WS2 - 15% is considered standard in the US (although this apparently varies by ethnicity). My wife prefers to give 20% (but doesn't count sale tax. Seems a lot of work for almost the same result to me).

Comment: It could be all sorts of things. It just doesn't make sense to me for a woman to call a man "good girl", it would be a strange as an insult. The term "good girl" sounds to me like what one says to a dog that has done well. Because she could have been saying (accidentally out loud) that she herself had been a 'good girl' and that the generous tip showed that. THis is all speculative. Things could have been misheard, slips of the tongue may have been made, too many levels of earnestness or sarcasm possible.

Comment: Don't take offense if you are not an American.  On the other hand, don't start using this yourself.

Comment: It wasn't a place like this London venue was it http://www.schooldinners.com/school-dinners.html? Male groups go there to be entertained by girls dressed as old-fashioned school-teachers, who treat them as young boys, smacking them and making them eat their leftovers. It all gets very sexy, I'm told. Parties of visiting Japanese businessmen love it!

Comment: @WS2 15% is considered the norm and even barest minimum in the Northeastern US. (I usually leave 20%)

Comment: Regardless of male or female patron, calling your patron a good girl for tipping is snide at the least. The person waiting the table shouldn't comment on the action at all (except, maybe, to point out an accidental omission), other than a polite Thank You. It's just the etiquette of the situation.  Even if they feel they were under tipped, it is still the protocol. And, if the under-tipper returns, perhaps their steak will fall on the floor a few times before it reaches the table.

Comment: I reckon it shows a kind of endearing chutzpah: it would be tempting to up-tip on hearing that. I'm surprised so many folks would be offended. I guess mileage varies.

Answer (score 7):

As an American, I honestly wouldn't know how to take it either.

OTOH, diner waitresses are kind of a special breed. Where most places the server tries to be part of the background, in a diner often the server is expected to be very personal. While most restaurants try to give a pleasant homogenous experience, in a diner one can expect to get a lot more local cultural flair. If there's a local accent or attitude, a diner waitress will often be playing it up to the extreme. For instance, people of both genders often get called things like "sweetie" or "honey", which is actually kind of condescending. They are expected to be snarky and have an attitude. There are even some places where [part of the draw is how rude](http://www.eddebevics.com/) they are to you.

So it could be some localish quirk she was playing up. Something that a non-American might not have thought twice about. For instance, perhaps you had what sounded to her like a disagreement over the size or person to provide the tip, and the person who paid it seemed to have lost. In that case, it might have been intended as a crack about the treatment the "good girl" received from his dining partner. Its tough to say without being there.

Answer (score 0):

It was just a slip of the tongue from.

Comment: Or perhaps it was an ironic commentary. Or perhaps it was an error based upon the androgyny of the dinner companion. Or …

Comment: ... perhaps it was a private joke between the two, or perhaps she was aware that the "male" customer was a pre-operative transsexual, or perhaps ...